# Ajuda com Infraestrutura

Tags: xml, web-service, segurança

Tenho um sistema Desktop que a cada 1 hora faz uma consulta no banco e gera um arquivo `.xml` e um sistema `javaWeb` que lê esse `.xml`. Eu desenvolvi essa solução pois a empresa que trabalho tem algumas normas de segurança onde não é permitido um sistema que ficará na Internet acessar a base de dados diretamente. Porém quando eu fizer o `deploy` desse sistema na nuvem ele terá que se conectar com o servidor da empresa para que consiga ler o `.xml` e isso também não seria seguro.

A primeira alternativa é fazer com que meu sistema desktop gere esses arquivos dentro de um servidor `FTP` no qual o sistema web tenha uma conexão e possa ler esses arquivos.

Porém tenho pensando se seria mais viável utilizar o conceito de `WebService` para resolver esse problema, e se eu criasse um sistema local que faça as consultas e o meu sistema que ficará na nuvem consumisse os dados?

Qual das opções parece ser a mais viável e segura?

Comment: Na minha opnião usar o WebService seria o mais adequado, porque no webservice você deixa disponivel apenas os métodos e informações que você quer, tendo um controle maior. Não recomendaria usar o FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebService seria uma forma elegante de resolver isso, um acesso crossdomain também resolveria, agora essa história do ftp fica meio que gambiarra ao meu ver.

**Edit**: viável e segura todas seriam ou teriam uma margem, se claro tudo for usado com as medidas cabíveis a cada uma delas.

Comment: Então eu também achei gambiarra kk, porém eu ainda não entendia muito bem o conceito de `WebService`.

Comment: Se tiver conhecimentos em PHP e/ou ajax sugiro crossdomain, se já tem alguma bagagem no JAVA é só dar uma lida e mão na massa

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado, vou fazer tudo em java mesmo.